# In python, what's the method to ask for a user input based on previous user input?

Tags: python, list, input

I have an assignment where I need to ask the user to input the total number of integers that will be in the data set, ask for each of the integers, and then add them into a list, then summarize the list into a dictionary.

For now I'm only worried about the user input part.

Here's what I have so far:

```
data = []
summary = {}

total_ints = int(raw_input('Total integers in data: '))

while total_ints:
  each_int = int(raw_input('Enter an integer: '))

data.append(each_int)
```

Basically I need to only print the 'each_int' input based on the number the user enters in 'total_ints'.  I know the while loop isn't correct, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This is a loop whose body is executed total_ints times:

```
for i in range(total_ints):
  data.append(int(raw_input('Enter an integer: ')))
```

Comment: D'oh, I knew it was something easy I was missing, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using while , use:

```
for x in range(0,total_ints):
```